# Running an Android activity with an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, run-configuration

I have an activity that requires a parameter be passed as an intent extra when the activity is started. Is there any way I can set a demo parameter from a run configuration to allow me to to run the activity from Android Studio without creating a temporary default activity that launches the activity I am working on?

Comment: I think the Launch Flags will work, using [the appropriate `am` switches for extras](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#am) (e.g., `-e foo bar` to set an extra named `foo` to the string value `bar`). I haven't tried this, though.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

With credit to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), here is the solution:

In the configuration, set the correct [flags](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#IntentSpec) for [`am`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#am), in my case `-e` for a `String` extra:

```
-e "extra_key" "extra_value"
```

Alternatively, for an `int` extra, you could use the flag `--ei`:

```
--ei "extra_key" 1
```

This goes in the "Launch Flags" field (with a specified activity) in the launch options section of the configuration edit dialog.